# Why are my binaries not placed in the /bin/release folder when I build a Windows Service in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, release-mode

I am new to C# and VS 2010, and am following an online guide to creating a C# Windows Service in Visual Studio 2010.

When I try and build the application however, I don't get any files created under the `/bin/release` folder.

I do get files under the `/bin/Debug` folder.

I have tried all the build configurations e.g Active, DEBUG, Release, All but nothing changes.

I have tried closing the solution down and restarting etc.

I have also experienced this same problem on a number of other projects which have been C# console apps.

The `/bin/release` folder exists (as I had to create it by hand) and I have checked the output path in the properties tab to ensure the release configuration is targeted to that folder.

I asked our "C# guru" at work and he didn't have a clue. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Does it work if you create a new empty project from scratch?

Comment: Do a build and watch the output window to see where the binaries are being created...

Answer (score 45):

Most likely, you are only *configuring* the Release build, not *actually building* the project in Release mode.

Simply select "Release" mode from the drop down box in the toolbar, as shown in pic below:

[image]

or you can do the same thing from your project's Properties:

[image]

Then when you will build the project (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>), it will build in Release mode and place the output in the folder you have configured in Project properties. (Usually this is `bin/release`.)

If you still don't see files in the release folder then as suggested by *Gishu* in the comments, check the Output Window while the build is in progress to see where the binaries are actually being created.

Comment: @Cody Gray thanx for edit.. i didn't knew about those <kbd> tags

Comment: Cheers Cody. That was it exactly. I didn't see that drop down and it was set to DEBUG which is why the RELEASE folder wasn't being populated.

Answer (score 9):

I witnessed the same problem.Even when I had the configuration as Release as shown above,VS will some how ignore it and as I can see from the output window,it puts it in the Debug folder.

Trick that worked for me:
1] Go to Build Tab on VS.
2] Click Configuration manager.
3] Under the drop down both at active solution configuration and the project specific configuration, select release.
4] Check the project properties just to make sure. Then build it.I the release folder the required files.

Accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: In my case, the output folder for god knows what reason was not set properly in the project properties

Comment: In my situation in the config mgr., debug was selected at the project level even though release was selected as the active config at the solution level. I had to switch all the projects to release.