# C# Console Application - Shortcut not apears in the "Sent to" menu

Tags: c#, windows

I build a C# Console application that takes a file in parameter, format it and save the result in an other file. I've built the application successfully using ClickOnce. Now I want to be able to click right on a given file and "Send To" my application. As for other application, I've sent the shortcut to the C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo repository but unlike other shortcut, my application is hidden from the menu. I've tested on few other PC (also running under Windows 7) and I always get the same behavior.

Do you know if it's caused by ClickOnce? Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I finally bypass the ClickOnce solution and use the plain .exe instead. The post below describe how to achieve it:

[Why are my binaries not placed in the /bin/release folder when I build a Windows Service in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929126/why-are-my-binaries-not-placed-in-the-bin-release-folder-when-i-build-a-windows?answertab=votes#tab-top)